# What is the underlying backend of graphql?

Tags: graphql

I sort of understand how the graphql engine works with its querying ability etc.

How does graphql actually connect to the backend datastores like postgresql etc.

Is this a nodejs application or a more scalable backend written in java/golang could be used by graphql?

Sorry I'm not sure I understand the various components required to use graphql and hoping someone could explain that to me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if I understand it correctly you define the back-end for your GraphQL implementation. See here for supported languages: http://graphql.org/code/

One of the primary things GraphQL does is allow the client to define what gets returned rather than the Api, you build out your Api with the GraphQL libraries and define schemas to map your data logically.

Here's a good article that shows how this can be done with React for the client and Node for the back-end: https://www.sitepoint.com/graphql-overview/